# How many I/O connections can be made to Google Spreadsheet from Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, api, spreadsheet, userscripts

How many I/O connections can be made to Google Spreadsheet from Javascript API using
Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 2):

Google doesn't state a limit and probably doesn't officially have one.

[The Google Spreadsheets API Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/terms) just refers to [the Google APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/terms/). which currently just says:

> Google ***may*** set limits on the number of API requests that you can make, at its sole discretion

(Emphasis added).

If you look at [the Google Apps *Pricing* page](http://www.google.com/intl/en/enterprise/apps/business/pricing.html) and click the <kbd>Compare more features</kbd> button, you'll see that Google limits (and charges for) use of high-resource intensive stuff like storage, users, and domains.  (Plus maps for the Map API.)

"Normal" API's are just listed as a given, and probably won't be limited unless abuse becomes a problem (Not likely or it would have happened already).

What makes you think that Google's limiting you?
Or are you just asking a hypothetical?

See, also, [Google spreadsheets size and complexity limits](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2505921).